# Get all rows from table1 and not exists in table2 with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, join

I have a online test where I have two tables `t1` (lvl_addition) question table and `t2` (student_answers) answer table. `t1` table has 100 sums.

Student has to answer the sum one by one and every answer will saves in the `t2` table using the `fk` of `t1`

```
t1
-----
id
test_FK
modepaper_FK
sum1
sum2
...
answ (original answer)

t2
-----
id
t1_FK
student_FK
modelpaper_FK
answ (student answer)

modelpaper_FK is referred to the modelpaper table id, and student_FK is for the student_profiles id.
```

The exam is time based, if the time ends before they finish all 100 sums. The exam stops and the `t2` table will have only the answered sums.

#### What iam looking for

i need to output all the 100 sums from the `t1` table (even if doesn't exists in `t2`). Iam using `NOT EXIST` clause but the problem is i also need to use `WHERE` clause to refer `t1.id = n AND t2.student_FK = n`

How can i do that.

The code below gets me only the answered sums from t2.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM lvl_additions t1 
LEFT JOIN student_answers t2 ON t1.id = t2.lvladditions_FK
WHERE t1.modelpaper_FK = 59 AND t2.studentprofile_FK = 279
```

Comment: In the query your tried you have written "t1.modelpaper_FK" is modelpaper_FK in t1 or t2 ? In your schema above, it is in t2

Comment: @Gosfly both has modelpaper_FK. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastian said, the problem comes from the following condition :

> t2.studentprofile_FK = 279

What you have to do is to move this condition and any other condition on t2 right inside the left join 'on' clause. See the query below :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.t1_fk AND t2.student_id = 2)
```

And the most important : [**SEE COMPLETE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=47924a194692d95bf5b59496a799207e)

**EDIT after discussion in chat :**

The OP needs to get every questions/answers to a modelpaper for a specific student, even if there is not an answer to every question in the modelpaper. In this case, a text will be displayed in place of the null answer.

1. There are more than 4500 questions
2. Questions are "grouped by" modelpaper, each modelpaper contains 100 questions
3. A student may have answered to every questions in a modelpaper

Based on these information, the following query did the job :

```
SELECT
     t1.*,
     COALESCE(t2.answ, 'replacement text')
FROM lvl_additions t1
LEFT JOIN student_answers t2 ON (t1.id = t2.lvladditions_FK AND t2.studentprofile_FK = 279)
WHERE t1.modelpaper_fk = 59
```

**EDIT 2 :**

There are 2 cases to differenciate :

1. Student runs out of time, answer is null and ctime is null (ctime is a column in t2 that records duration)
2. Student skips a question, answer is null but ctime is 00:00:00

The following query allows us to display a different text for each case :

```
SELECT
     t1.*,
     IF(t2.ctime IS NULL, 'time runs out', IF(t2.ctime = 0, 'question skipped', t2.answ)) AS answer
FROM lvl_additions t1
LEFT JOIN student_answers t2 ON (t1.id = t2.lvladditions_FK AND t2.studentprofile_FK = 279)
WHERE t1.modelpaper_fk = 59
```

Comment: your code works if you do not add the modelpaper_FK. But i need `WHERE t1.modelpaper_FK = 59 AND t2.studentprofile_FK = 279`. Iam using `t1` here because it has all 100 sums.

Comment: just add "WHERE t1.modelpaper_FK = 59" after the left join ! If it doesn't work, that means your modelpaper 59 doesn't contain all 100 sums...

Comment: I did, It shows only the answers from the t2 table and all the 100 sums.

Comment: "It shows only the answers from the t2 table and all the 100 sums" ??? it is a filter on t1 table, it can't filter answers from t2. Btw, isn't it what you want ? all answers from t2 where student id is 279 and all 100 sums ?

Comment: Just run "select * from t1 where modelpaper_fk = 59", this can't return you 100 sums

Comment: I need to show all 100 sums + whatever the student answers. The left over answers can be set as null or nil. But iam looking for all 100 sums.

Comment: I think i have already mentioned this in my question (under 'What Iam looking for') `i need to output all the 100 sums from the t1 table (even if doesn't exists in t2).`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206570/discussion-between-gosfly-and-dexter).